# Grouping array elements into weeks by date variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array called items which contains 29 items. Each item has a date, name, code and week number.
I am trying to group these items by their week number in typescript. Can anyone help with this please?

This is what my array looks like currently:

```
items:
0:
   code: "N"
   date: "2020-10-13T01:00:00.000Z"
   name: "Tuesday"
   week: 7
1:
   code: "N"
   date: "2020-10-13T01:00:00.000Z"
   name: "Tuesday"
   week: 7
2: {date: "2020-10-12T01:00:00.000Z", name: "Monday", code: "O", …}
3: {date: "2020-10-12T01:00:00.000Z", name: "Monday", code: "O", …}
```

ETC - up to 29. However I want it grouped by weeks as follows. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
weeks:

0:
     days: 
          0:{name:Monday, date: ####, code:###}
          0:{name:Tuesday, date: ####, code:###}
1:
     days: 
          0:{name:Monday, date: ####, code:###}
          0:{name:Tuesday, date: ####, code:###}
2:
     days: 
          0:{name:Monday, date: ####, code:###}
          0:{name:Tuesday, date: ####, code:###}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `groupBy` from `lodash` package (with a little postprocessing) or simply use `for` like this:

```
const weeks: Record<string, any> = {};
for (const item of items) {
  if (!weeks[item.week]) {
    weeks[item.week] = {
     days: []
    }
  }
  weeks[item.week].days.push({
    name: item.name,
    date: item.date,
    code: item.code
  })
}
```

Note: instead of `any` you should indicate some type with days array prop where each element has name, date and code props

Comment: Thanks, if I push this weeks array into my academic_year.graphData array like this:    academic_year.graphData.push({weeks}); When I try to console log the weeks like this:          console.log(academic_year.graphData); I get this error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: No problem. Just turn Record into an array like this: `const weeksArray = Object.values(weeks)`

Comment: Better turn this into a new question on SO